# How to retrieve data from sparkql to UI?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark. Please help me to solve the below question. I followed the below steps.

1. I logged into spark-shell and created the hive context by using below code

   ```
    scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
    scala> val hivec = new HiveContext(sc);
   ```

2.Executed below query

```
scala> val db = hivec.sql("select * from person_data.export_project")
```

3. ran the show query

   ```
   scala> db.show()
   ```
4. Got the results as below

> ```
> id    firstname  lastname PhoneNo
> 111   xxxx       cccc     11111111
> 222   aaaa       bbbb     22222222
> ```

I want to show above result(data) in UI, how can I show it. Could you please help me to get in detail steps.

Comment: Which UI are you talking about?

Comment: Like in hive we have jdbc connectivity where were provide the hive drive details,hive port number and other details. in the same way do we have something in spark to get the data to front end screen.

Comment: If you start Spark thriftserver you can connect to it via jdbc as well, is this what you want to do?

Comment: yes, Could you please provide me the steps as well some pseudo code also...

Answer (score 0):

Here (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-thrift-jdbcodbc-server) you can find the steps required to start the SparkSQL thriftserver. When you've done with this, you can connect to it via JDBC (the default port is 10015 or 10000).